# How to prevent Git (Bitbucket) from merging big files?

Tags: c#, git, merge, bitbucket

A few months ago a developer pushed and merged a feature branch into our main branch (develop) that contained test files (800MB). I deleted these files from Bitbucket and everything (it was a pain). Now I am looking for a solution that could prevent this from happening in the future.

Is there some kind of process/script that I could run before performing a merge to my main branch? I would like this process to check every single file in the solution and verify that every file is less than 2.00MB.

Not sure if this will help or not, but the solution consists of various C# projects, including unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the git hooks to prevent this, either on receiving a push in the central repo, or before merging.